# Running Glassfish asadmin Commands via Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, glassfish-2.x

I'm trying to create an automated deployment via Jenkins that deploys an application to Glassfish-2.1.

The problem comes when Jenkins is running the following commands:

```
sh /usr/local/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --user admin --passwordfile /usr/local/glassfish/passwordfile.txt domain1

sh /usr/local/glassfish/bin/asadmin deploy -s --contextroot admin /tmp/artifacts/$admin_war_file_name
```

But Jenkins just hangs, apparently waiting for the password.  However, I can run this script manaually on the server and it works.

Also, I was curious if this ok from a security standpoint?  Should I actually be storing the master password (if in fact I can even get Jenkins to run these commands in the first place!)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have worked for largest ecommerce company still they store master passwords in jenkins, but use this plugin- MASK Password plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin

Comment: and also try giving full path for shell editor for example /usr/bin/ksh or /usr/bin/bash